# Are there criminal Lamborghini gangs in Japan?

Tags: japan

According to this article on [Elite Daily](http://elitedaily.com/envision/cars/forget-biker-gangs-actual-lamborghini-gangs-japan-video/621742/):

> There are all types of gangs in the world: biker gangs, street gangs;
>   you name it. But what if we told you that there’s a Lamborghini gang
>   in Japan?
>
> No, seriously, there is! In a recent video uploaded to YouTube by
>   Maiham-Media, a new short documentary was featured called “Underground
>   Hero: Love To Hate Me.”
>
> During the documentary, we’re introduced to a Japanese man named
>   Morohoshi-san, who is the leader of this gang, where he and all of his
>   members commit deadly crimes and drive around in souped up
>   Lamborghinis. It’s pretty crazy stuff and there’s a high chance that you’ve never seen anything like this before!

The short documentary can be [viewed here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRIsHRHNU5k#t=259)

Comment: While the article calls it documentary, the author himself seem to intentionally avoid this word, or say that it is a real-life story, or anything equivalent. So, the premise is questionable - it is not a documentary and is not claimed to be (if such claim exists, please link to it, I was not able to find such).

Comment: From what I've seen myself and heard from natives of Japan, almost every sequence in that video looks highly unlikely or outright fake. I'll try to scramble for some harder evidence when I have a minute unless there'll be a good answer before that...

Comment: @sashkello: Elite Daily makes a definite claim based on that video, so if you want to make an answer showing that the video doesn't support the claim, it seems good to me.